# asp.net dropdownlist and gridview

Tags: asp.net

I have created 2 DropdownList and 1 GridView

1st DropdownList Loads and Displays **DataBase** Names Dynamically

2nd DropdownList Loads and Displays **Table Names**, Based on Database name Which selected in 1st drop down list

Based on Table Name Data has to be displayed in GridView........

I have written code  which displays Database Names and working fine

```
private void populateDatabasename() {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SAI-           PC\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select name,collation_name from sys.databases order by name", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "dbname");
        DropDownList1.DataSource = ds.Tables["dbname"];
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "name";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "name";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
}
```

Based on Database name tables have to be displayed..... how to pass Database name(Which is selected in 1st drop down list) in the following code..... 
Is This a correct way to pass database name

```
private void populateTableName() {                

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SAI-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select name from "+"@Dbname"+".sys.tables", con);

        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@dbname", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters["@dbname"].Value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "dbname1");
        DropDownList2.DataSource = ds.Tables["dbname1"];
        DropDownList2.DataTextField = "name";
        DropDownList2.DataValueField = "name";
        DropDownList2.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: It may be by accident but in the `SqlDataAdapter` you used `@Dbname` with capital D and when you assign the parameter you used `@dbname` with a small d. Don't know if it's case sensitive.

Comment: Thank You....... I got the answer...................................            cmd.CommandText = "select name as TableName from " + drddatabase.SelectedValue + "." + "sys" + "." + "tables

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it required or not but you should give the db name in connection string. `Database=Northwind;` in this case, using `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder` class even better. And then you can query the table names if the user have correct rights.

Comment: Thank You....... I got the answer...................................                            cmd.CommandText = "select name as TableName from  " + drddatabase.SelectedValue + "." + "sys" + "." + "tables ";

Answer (score 0):

i think you should include DataBase name in connection string that you use to populate table

use something like this

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SAI-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=" + Dropdownlist1.selecteditem.text + ";Integrated Security=True");

then Read the tables and continue

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        string dbName = ddlDbName.SelectedValue;
        string strcon = "server=SAI-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;database= " + dbName + ";providerName=\"System.Data.SqlClient\"";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        con.Open();
```